# Click image to upload

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, image

I'm wondering if there's some way to prompt the image dialog box through javascript or html by clicking on an image. The ultimate goal is to have the image that is clicked on be a cropped version of the uploaded image and if you'd like to change it you click on it.

EDIT: Sorry for not being more clear, this is for a web page. When I say image dialog box I mean the file upload dialog box (the one you get when you use an html form). The idea is once the image is selected in the dialog box, it begins uploading to the site so it can be displayed immediately on the page.

Comment: Image dialog box ? What application are you talking of ? And what do you want to change when someone clicks on an image ? Please clarify your question and try to be WAY more specific!!

Comment: Please clarify 2 phrases in your question : "image dialog box" and "cropped version" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<A HREF="action here"><IMG SRC="image url" ALT="alt text"></A>
```

for action here, would be the action, for what you're attempting to do, i'd recomend using javascript

so it'd be like this (as an example)

```
<A HREF="javascript:imageStuff()"><IMG SRC="/images/this.png" ALT="alt text"></A>
```

Comment: That's supposed to be an answer ? The OP already asked for a JS solution and you not even provided any code apart from a link to an undefined function. Btw you need to indent code to get it displayed properly here...

Comment: he was asking how to have it use javascript, not for a javascript function "I'm wondering if there's some way to prompt the image dialog box through javascript"